# Facing Runtime Exception at Nutch Injector

Tags: maven, nutch

I am trying to crawl website using Apache Nutch but getting following exception. Tried both in NetBeans and Intellj IDE....Your suggestion would be of great help on this issue...

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Injector job did not succeed, job status: FAILED, reason: NA

````
``` at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:365)
``` at com.yegor256.nutch.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:82)

Process finished with exit code 1
````

Comment: Can you post your MainTest class code?

Comment: The full stack trace would also helpful. One possible reason: setting the classpath for Nutch isn't trivial because of the plugin system and the need for configuration files to be on the classpath. Better use the script src/bin/nutch which configures the classpath appropriately. Also: building Nutch requires `ant`, as of today, it cannot be built using Maven.